# What is the correct form of passing parameters to std::is_nothrow_assignable -like functions in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits, noexcept

I'm studying the functionality of the `noexcept` specifier and the `noexcept` operator.
I know that instead of using the `noexcept` operator, there are some type traits that are an alternative to use like:

```
- is_nothrow_constructible
- is_nothrow_default_constructible
- is_nothrow_move_constructible
- is_nothrow_copy_constructible
- is_nothrow_assignable
- is_nothrow_move_assignable
- is_nothrow_copy_assignable
- is_nothrow_destructible
```

For example, in the case of the `is_nothrow_assignable` and `is_nothrow_constructible`.

```
struct A { };
struct B {
  B& operator= (const A&) noexcept {return *this;}
  B& operator= (const B&) {return *this;}
};

int main() {
  std::cout << std::boolalpha;
  std::cout << "is_nothrow_assignable:" << std::endl;
  std::cout << "A=A: " << std::is_nothrow_assignable<A,A>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "B=A: " << std::is_nothrow_assignable<B,A>::value << std::endl;
  std::cout << "B=B: " << std::is_nothrow_assignable<B,B>::value << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above, it is clear that it tests if one type can be non-throw assignable like `std::is_nothrow_assignable<B, A>`.

But, I see in some templates of the C++ standard library that they pass the arguments with `const` and/or `&/&&` and some others don't use that, something like this definition of the `std::exchange`:

```
_EXPORT_STD template <class _Ty, class _Other = _Ty>
_CONSTEXPR20 _Ty exchange(_Ty& _Val, _Other&& _New_val) noexcept(
    conjunction_v<is_nothrow_move_constructible<_Ty>, is_nothrow_assignable<_Ty&, _Other>>) { // HERE
    // assign _New_val to _Val, return previous _Val
    _Ty _Old_val = static_cast<_Ty&&>(_Val);
    _Val         = static_cast<_Other&&>(_New_val);
    return _Old_val;
}
```

The parameter types of `std::exchange` are: `_Ty&, _Other&&`.

In the third line of the function uses the `is_nothrow_assignable` as:

```
    is_nothrow_assignable<_Ty&, _Other>
    //                       ^        ^
    //                       |        |
    // Here is passing as reference   |
    //                               But not here
```

And in other functions is something similar:

```
//const& ----------------
//          |           |
pair(const T1& x, const T2& y) noexcept(  
        is_nothrow_constructible<T1, const T1&>::value &&
        is_nothrow_constructible<T2, const T2&>::value );
//                               ^     ^     ^
//                               |     |     |
// Here without const or & ------      |     |
//                                     |     |
// But here is with const and & -------------
```

My question is why they use `const` and or `&/&&` in some arguments and in others don't?
And how can I determine when/where to use them?

Comment: (I appreciate the effort you put into your ASCII-art diagrams and using aligned syntax features for legibility - have an upvote - because sometimes I think I'm the only one in the world who cares about stuff like that)

Comment: Consider what happens - the `pair` constructor creates a `T1` from the `const  T1&` parameter `x`, so "obviously" `is_nothrow_constructible<T1, const T1&>`. Could also be written `is_nothrow_copy_constructible<T1>`!  The `exchange` example involves a forwarding reference, which makes it *way* more complicated (and too hard for me to write a proper answer).

Comment: Yes. But, "I think", it also works the same way if used like `is_nothrow_constructible<T1, T1>`. I mean, not using `const&`, like in the first example with `<B, B>`, because even if is not a template, the parameter in `B` assignment is `const B&` and in the `is_nothrow_assignable<B, B>` returns `true`.

Answer (score 1):

`is_nothrow_assignable<T, U>` tells you, given

```
T&& f();
U&& g();
```

whether `f() = g()` is valid and non-throwing.

Due to [reference collapsing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Reference_collapsing), when `T` is a reference, `T&&` is the same as `T`. Otherwise, `T&&` is "rvalue reference to `T`", as you may have expected.

So, for some object types `A`, `B`,

- `is_nothrow_assignable<A, B>` tells you whether an **rvalue** of type `A` can be assigned from an **rvalue** of type `B` without potentially throwing an exception. This is hardly interesting, because you rarely need to assign to an rvalue.
- `is_nothrow_assignable<A&&, B&&>` is equivalent to `is_nothrow_assignable<A, B>`.
- `is_nothrow_assignable<A&, const B&>` tells you whether an **lvalue** of type `A` can be assigned from a **const lvalue** of type `B` without potentially throwing an exception.
- `is_nothrow_assignable<A&, B>` tells you whether an **lvalue** of type `A` can be assigned from an **rvalue** of type `B` without potentially throwing an exception.
- `is_nothrow_assignable<A&, B&&>` is equivalent to `is_nothrow_assignable<A&, B>`.

Comment: `T` and `T &&` are not fully equivalent in traits. If `T` is incomplete, the former is a hard error in some compilers (Clang and MSVC reject; GCC accepts), while the latter is ok.

Comment: @cpplearner Thank you. I'm doing some research, and also with your answer, I'm understanding everything better. But, in my first example with `A` and `B`, if `B` copy assign operator is receiving `const B&` and `const A&`. Why the `is_nothrow_assignable<B, A>` IS NOT using the `const A&` as second argument like this: `is_nothrow_assignable<B, const A&>` ?

Comment: So, for my understanding, a `const&` can bind to both, lvalues and rvalues and either `is_nothrow_assignable<B, A>` or `is_nothrow_assignable<B, const A&>` have the same effect? And in this particular case `B` and `A` are not class templates, so, it doesn't matter but it does if are templates? Please correctme if I am wrong. I'm still learning.